# Microsoft Outlook Add-In for non 365 Users

Tags: office-js, office-store

I have noticed that only a select few of Outlook add-ins show up in Outlook for mac add-ins section when you are using outlook with an email address hosted outside of Office 365. If I build an add-in, how would I go about getting my add-in to show up on this list as well as the main list in the AppSource store. Has anyone done this?

Comment: I'd appreciate the green tick if that has answered your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

By default your add-in will appear in the Outlook for Mac as well. The list of add-ins which don't appear in Outlook for Mac are the ones which are using a functionality that doesn't exist yet in the Mac client. If you check this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets

It shows you what features are available in what versions of the clients. If your add-in is using a newer functionality (1.7 as of now, which you can specify in your manifest) which only shipped to some Windows clients and not the Mac yet, your add-in won't appear on Mac list. If you are browsing the store and not seeing Mac add-ins perhaps you are due an update :) Eventually though we should see all of the add-ins on all of the platforms supported.